# Optimizing word counter

Tags: python, optimization, programming-challenge

I took the Python class at Google code today, and this is what I made for the problem about building a word counter.

Please take a look and suggest any improvements that can be done.  Please do point out the bad practices if I have used any.

```
import sys

def make_dict(filename):
    """returns a word/count dictionary for the given input file"""
    myFile=open(filename,'rU')
    text=myFile.read()
    words=text.lower().split()
    wordcount_dict={}   #map each word to its count
    for word in words:
        wordcount_dict[word]=0
    for word in words:
        wordcount_dict[word]=wordcount_dict[word]+1
    myFile.close()
    return  wordcount_dict

def print_words(filename):
    """prints each word in the file followed by its count"""
    wordcount_dict=make_dict(filename)
    for word in wordcount_dict.keys():
        print word, "  " , wordcount_dict[word]

def print_top(filename):
    """prints the words with the top 20 counts"""
    wordcount_dict=make_dict(filename)
    keys = wordcount_dict.keys()
    values = sorted(wordcount_dict.values())
    for x in xrange (1,21): #for the top 20 values
        for word in keys :
            if wordcount_dict[word]==values[-x]:
                print word, "       ",wordcount_dict[word]

def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'usage: ./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file'
    sys.exit(1)

  option = sys.argv[1]
  filename = sys.argv[2]
  if option == '--count':
    print_words(filename)
  elif option == '--topcount':
    print_top(filename)
  else:
    print 'unknown option: ' + option
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the way you've broken down the code into functions, I think it makes sense and avoids repetition or duplication of code and functionality.

One slight improvement to consider here is to have `print_words` and `print_top` take the dictionary returned from `make_dict` rather than calling it as their first step. In addition to avoiding a tiny amount of duplicated code, this sort of "function composition" when used effectively can be a very powerful design pattern, allowing very expressive and readable code for more complicated problems than this one.

A few other specific thoughts:

In `make_dict`, you're reading the entire file contents into memory, and then processing each word twice. This works well enough for small files, but imagine that you had a 500 gigabyte text file? In this case, reading the file into memory ("buffering" it) will lead to a program crash, or at the very least, very bad performance.

Instead, you can actually iterate the file in a `for` loop, which will only read small portions of the file into memory at once. This requires a slight change to your logic in `make_dict`:

```
myFile=open(filename,'rU')
wordcount_dict={}   #map each word to its count
for line in myFile:
    # .strip() removes the newline character from the
    # end of the line, as well as any leading or trailing
    # white-space characters (spaces, tabs, etc)
    words = line.strip().lower().split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in wordcount_dict:
            wordcount_dict[word] = 0
        wordcount_dict[word] += 1
```

In `print_words`, you're using `.keys()` to get the words from the `wordcount_dict`, then accessing those keys from the dictionary. This works fine, but Python dictionaries allow you to get *items* (that is, key-value pairs) directly when iterating a dictionary, using `.items()` instead of `.keys()`:

```
for word, count in wordcount_dict.items():
    print word, "  " , count
```

`items()` returns a list of length-2 tuples, and the `for word, count in ...` syntax "unpacks" those tuples into the variables `word` and `count`.

Building on this technique, we can simplify `print_top` as well. Once we have in hand a list of each (word, count) pair (the length-2 tuples), we can sort that list, and then print only the top 20 words (ranked by their count):

```
wordcount_dict=make_dict(filename)
word_count_pairs = wordcount_dict.items()
word_count_pairs.sort(
    # use a "key" function to return the sort key
    # for each item in the list we are sorting; here
    # we return index 1 -- that is, the count -- to
    # sort by that
    key=lambda pair: pair[1],

    # reverse the sort so that the words with the
    # highest counts come first in the sorted list
    reverse=True
)

# make a copy of the first 20 elements of the
# list, using slice notation
top_word_count_pairs = word_count_pairs[:20]

for word, count in top_word_count_pairs:
    print word, "       ",wordcount_dict[word]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have to prepare a word counter, then the more adequate container is `collections.defaultdict`

Then your `make_dict` function could be written much more simply:

```
def make_dict(filename):
    """returns a word/count dictionary for the given input file"""
    wordcount_dict = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'rU') as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            words = line.strip().lower().split()
            for word in words:      
                wordcount_dict[word] += 1
    return wordcount_dict
```

Note that you don't need to care about initialization of dictionary entries for new keys for word counting, as `defaultdict` takes care of it.

**Another different approach is to use OOP**. That is, to create a word counter object with state initialization, methods and all the stuff. The code gets simplified, encapsulated and ready to be extended.

Below, there is a working OOP proposal. There are some improvements that can be implemented also in your functional version if you don't like OOP:

1) I simplified your methods. Now there is only one method `print_words(self, number=None)`. If you want the best 20 then just indicate the number of words.

2) I included some optimizations to clean words that are splitted with punctuation characters (otherwise `house`, `house.` and `house'` would be counted as different), using constants from the `string` module.

```
non_chars = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
words = [item.strip(non_chars).lower() for item in line.split()]
```

3) I used `operator.itemgetter` for the sorting key (instead of lambdas. More readable, imho)

4) I used formatting for the print for a better look. Used classical `%`.

```
import operator
import string
from collections import defaultdict

class WordCounter(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        defaultdict.__init__(self, int)
        self.file = filename
        self._fill_it()

    def _fill_it(self):
        "fill dictionary"
        non_chars = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
        with open(self.file, 'rU') as myFile:
            for line in myFile:
                words = [item.strip(non_chars).lower() for item in line.split()]
                for word in words:      
                    self[word] += 1

    def print_words(self, number=None):
        """prints the words with the top <number> counts"""
        wc_pairs = self.items()
        wc_pairs.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        number = number or len(wc_pairs)
        for word, count in wc_pairs[:number]:
            print "%-20s%5s" % (word, count)


my_wc = WordCounter('testme.txt')

print my_wc['aword']    # print 'aword' counts
my_wc.print_words()     # print all (sorted by counts)
my_wc.print_words(3)    # print top 3
```

And a final note: leaving a blank space before and after an operator and after commas in lists, increases readability of the text and is considered good practice.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write `make_dict` function this way:

```
def make_dict(filename):
    wordcount_dict={}
    with open(filename,'rU') as myFile:
        for line in myFile:
            words = line.strip().lower().split()
            for word in words:
                wordcount_dict.setdefault(word, 0)        
                wordcount_dict[word] += 1
    return wordcount_dict
```

`With` keyword closes file automatically if exception happens. 
{}.setdefault() is more pythonic than the condition which @dcrosta suggested.

What about `main` function, there is an excellent python library [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), which helps parsing command line options. Check it if you need more complex user interface.

Comment: i was not aware of the setdefault() method of dictionary .with..as thing is new to me too..and about optparse , i am just starting out .So I guess i'll check that out later..thanks for the tip though :)